# Kibana stacked bar breakdown by text/tag

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm trying to create a stacked bar visualisation for runtimes from a series of logs. The logs have start and end times, and a "subtask" text field. I want to breakdown the runtimes such that each segment in a stacked bar shows how long a subtask took, with the whole bar therefore showing the total time of the task.

I have it set up as:

- x-axis = start times, interval 1 hour
- y-axis = start time-end time (scripted field)

I want to breakdown the y-axis, but kibana doesn't allow me to do this using a text field. What data type should I be using to achieve this?

Comment: it might be worth looking at using a runtime field instead of a scripted on, as you will get the better mapping output. or, ideally, calculate the difference during ingestion. that aside, you will probably want to group by subtask as well, so that it aggregates the times together

Comment: How would I group by subtask?